# What is the difference between importing js library or reference it in html <script> tag

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, webpack

I am currently working with webpack with react js. I am new to it and have a question about the importing dependencies. In traditional way, we usually import a third party library from the `<script>` tag in html. Now I can do it in the javascript by running below code. I wonder what the difference between these two approaches is. Whether they are imported into a same namespace? Is there any other difference?

```
import $ from 'jquery'
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import load from 'little-loader';
```

Comment: this is a thing you can *probably* find with some tactical googling. http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html

Comment: It sounds like you have a question on the core use case of webpack.  It just lets you import modules and the scoping is local to wherever you do the import. If you wanted to make something global you would do `import $ from 'jquery'; window.$ = $;` But you should be using modules and not use global namespaces.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your explaination.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll notice that Webpack generates a JS file which **is** included via a `<script>` tag. This is the "bundled" file. You always have a `<script>` tag on the page.

What Webpack/Browserify/etc. do, is they take several different JS files and combine them into one JS file to load via a `<script>` tag. So this:

```
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

...becomes this:

```
<script src="bundle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

jQuery and all your `app.js` code is now inside the `bundle.js` file. Webpack will also make sure that everything is in the right order, so that jQuery runs before the `app.js` code. That's why you have this line:

```
import $ from 'jquery'
```

...or in ECMAScript 5:

```
var $ = require('jquery');
```

This tells the bundler that you depend on jQuery, so it can make sure it is 1) included and 2) included in correct order.